# Is it possible to disable all bounds?

Tags: ios, mapbox

Is there anyway to totally disable bounds on a map? Using the iOS SDK.

I have a base layer which works well but every time I need to add a new top layer the bounds get magically locked to the whatever the extents of the new layers have. I need people to be able to drag between cities on the map at whole.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `RMCompositeSource` tile source, which uses Core Graphics to composite an array of sub-tile sources into single tiles for display, and uses the bounds and zoom limits of the composite source instead. You might get a performance boost out of this as well.

Comment: Sorry for the lateness! Just revisited this problem today and saw you post, I'll check it out and let ya know!